# How to make Typescript understand that value can't be null after function call that throws if value is null

Tags: typescript

I have a function that checks if a value is not null, that throws if the value is null. If it doesn't throw and returns successfully, i know that the value can't possibly be null.

Typescript doesn't seem to understand this without resorting to if cases. Is there any way to achieve this?

See the code below for clarification:

```
function ensureNotNull<T>(arg: T | null, paramName: string): arg is Exclude<typeof arg, null> {
    if (arg === null) {
        throw new Error(`arg '${paramName}' is null`);
    }

    return true;
}

var value: string | null = null;

function doStuffIfValueNotNull(value: string | null) : void {
    ensureNotNull<string>(value, "value");
    var strLen = value.length; //Error with strictNullChecks
}
```

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with `strictNullChecks`, but it seems to me that if you know it's not `null`, you can force the compiler to believe you by using `!`: `var strLen = value!.length;`

Comment: FYI, this is [the declined suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8655) you are wanting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make `ensureNotNull` return the non-`null` and assign it back (changes marked with `***`):

```
function ensureNotNull<T>(arg: T | null, paramName: string): T {
// *** ------------------------------------------------------^
    if (arg === null) {
        throw new Error(`arg '${paramName}' is null`);
    }

    return arg; // ***
}

var value: string | null = null;

function doStuffIfValueNotNull(value: string | null) : void {
    value = ensureNotNull<string>(value, "value");
//  ^^^^^^^^---- ***
    var strLen = value.length;
}
```

Alternately, `if` (but...blech, it suggests the method will return when in fact it will throw):

```
function doStuffIfValueNotNull(value: string | null) : void {
    if (!ensureNotNull<string>(value, "value")) return;
    var strLen = value.length; //Error with strictNullChecks
}
```

Comment: This looks like the best possible solution to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to cast it to the expected type.

```
    ensureNotNull<string>(value, "value");
    var strLen = (value as string).length;
```

Or use the [Non-null Assertion Operator Postfix `!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) (aka "magic punctuation" :-)

```
    ensureNotNull<string>(value, "value");
    var strLen = value!.length;
```